# How to save JSON data from a specific url into a javascript array and access through it? BASED ON ID

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, json, model-view-controller

I am new to Json and Javascript . Please find attached my application picture and snippet , also . [JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH44d.png)

What i am trying to do is , when i click the plus sign (inside the datatable) , it should display the order details into a dynamically generated html table , with headers , rows and cells  , for every Order ID. I am trying to store the JSON data from url into an array and than loop through it , and than display them corresponding every Order ID into a html table . So this is my View and script included :

```
e<style>

td.details-control {
background: url('/Content/images/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
width:40px;
height:5px;
cursor: pointer;}tr.details td.details-control {
background: url('/Content/images/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
width:40px;
height:5px;
```

}

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Order  ID</th>

            <th>Customer ID</th>
            <th>ContactName</th>
            <th>Employee ID</th>
            <th>Order Date</th>
            <th>Required Date</th>
            <th>Ship Via</th>
            <th>Freight</th>
            <th>Ship name</th>
            <th>Ship Address</th>
            <th>Ship City</th>
            <th>Ship Region</th>
            <th>Ship Postal</th>
            <th>Ship Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Order  ID</th>

            <th>Customer ID</th>
            <th>ContactName</th>

            <th>Employee ID</th>
            <th>Order Date</th>
            <th>Required Date</th>
            <th>Ship Via</th>
            <th>Freight</th>
            <th>Ship name</th>
            <th>Ship Address</th>
            <th>Ship City</th>
            <th>Ship Region</th>
            <th>Ship Postal</th>
            <th>Ship Country</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

</table>
```

```js
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<script>

    
     function format(d) {



        var jqxhr = $.getJSON("/Test/GetData", function (jsonResult) {
            ParseJson(jsonResult);
        })

        function ParseJson(response) {
            var html = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                var id = response[i].OrderID;
                html += "<tr>";
                html += "<td>" + response[i].ProductID + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + response[i].ProductName + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + response[i].UnitPrice + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + response[i].Quantity + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + response[i].Discount + "</td>";
                ///other td
                html += "</tr>";
            }
            $(document).find("#entrydata").html(html);
        }




         return '<table id = "entrydata" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +

             '<thead>' +
             '<th>PRODUCT ID</th>' +
                 '<th>PRODUCT  NAME</th>' +
                 '<th>UNIT PRICE</th>' +
                 '<th>QUANTITY</th>' +
                 '<th>DISCOUNT</th>' +
                 '</thead>' +
                '<tbody>' +

             '</tbody>' +

         '</table>';




    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dt = $('#example').DataTable({

            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Test/GetData",
                "type": "GET",
                "dataSrc": "",
                "method": "GET",


                "dataType": "json",
                "  destroy": true




            },
            "columns":
                [

                    {
                        "class": "details-control",
                        "orderable": false,
                        "data": null,
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                      { "data": "OrderID" },
                   { "data": "CustomerID" },
                      { "data": "ContactName" },
                    { "data": "EmployeeID", },
                    { "data": "OrderDate" },
                    { "data": "RequiredDate" },
                    { "data": "ShipVia" },
                    { "data": "Freight" },
                        { "data": "ShipName" },
                            { "data": "ShipAddress" },
                                { "data": "ShipCity" },
                                    { "data": "ShipRegion" },
                                        { "data": "ShipPostalCode" },
                                            { "data": "ShipCountry" }

                ],
            "order": [[1, 'asc']]

        });

        var detailRows = [];

        $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr td.details-control', function () {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var row = dt.row( tr );
            var idx = $.inArray( tr.attr('id'), detailRows );

            if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
                tr.removeClass( 'details' );
                row.child.hide();

                // Remove from the 'open' array
                detailRows.splice( idx, 1 );
            }
            else {
                tr.addClass('details');

                row.child( format( row.data() ) ).show();

                // Add to the 'open' array
                if ( idx === -1 ) {
                    detailRows.push( tr.attr('id') );
                }
            }
        } );

        // On each draw, loop over the `detailRows` array and show any child rows
        dt.on( 'draw', function () {
            $.each( detailRows, function ( i, id ) {
                $('#'+id+' td.details-control').trigger( 'click' );
            } );
        } );
    } );







</script>
```

```css
td.details-control {
    background: url('/Content/images/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    width:40px;
    height:5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.details td.details-control {
    background: url('/Content/images/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
    width:40px;
    height:5px;
}
```

```html
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Order  ID</th>

                <th>Customer ID</th>
                <th>ContactName</th>
                <th>Employee ID</th>
                <th>Order Date</th>
                <th>Required Date</th>
                <th>Ship Via</th>
                <th>Freight</th>
                <th>Ship name</th>
                <th>Ship Address</th>
                <th>Ship City</th>
                <th>Ship Region</th>
                <th>Ship Postal</th>
                <th>Ship Country</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
   
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Order  ID</th>

                <th>Customer ID</th>
                <th>ContactName</th>

                <th>Employee ID</th>
                <th>Order Date</th>
                <th>Required Date</th>
                <th>Ship Via</th>
                <th>Freight</th>
                <th>Ship name</th>
                <th>Ship Address</th>
                <th>Ship City</th>
                <th>Ship Region</th>
                <th>Ship Postal</th>
                <th>Ship Country</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>

    </table>
```

```
I have attached also a picture of JSON request from postman :[postman][2]
```

Comment: Any idea here ?

Comment: I think you should describe what the problem is, what you expect to happen and what errors you are getting.

Comment: Please see the image attached , when i click the plus sign to any Order ID , it should display ORDER DETAILS TO THAT ORDER ID , not all the ORDER DETAILS from the database like in the picture.